# Opening multiple FTP connections

Tags: java, ftp-client

I'm opening multiple FTP connections in my code in different threads.
There can be two connections to the same FTP server using the same credentials.

Can this cause a problem with the active/passive backchannel transfering the data? The actual problem I'm having is that a certain login fails even though it worked seconds before in a different thread. It is hard to reproduce.

Another question, is active or passive the standard setting? Which one is better?

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

ftp.setDefaultTimeout(timeoutMilliseconds);
ftp.setDataTimeout(timeoutMilliseconds);
ftp.setConnectTimeout(timeoutMilliseconds);
//ftp.setSoTimeout(1000);
//ftp.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(1000);
//ftp.setControlKeepAliveReplyTimeout(1000);

ftp.connect(serverAddress, serverPort);
logger.info("Connected successfully to " + serverAddress + ":" + serverPort);
boolean login = ftp.login(username, password);
logger.info("Logged in successfully to " + serverAddress + ":" + serverPort);


ftp.disconnect();
```

Comment: Have you considered that the server may be limiting the number of connections it will accept from one client address or network?  FTP servers are commonly configured to do this to limit hogging, mitigate denial of service, etcetera.

Comment: There are two instances of the application, and each will only have up to two connections to the same FTP server. I'm not sure whether the FTP server has such a low limit. In addition, the error only happens in the preproduction instance, and I have a hard time convincing my boss that it isn't a bug in the new code.

Comment: These are two distinct connections. They cannot possibly affect each other at the client end. But they certainly can at the server, if it doesn't allow them. It would help considerably if you provided the actual error message. Active vs passive mode has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Passive mode is recommended. Please find the below settings that I have used in my project. You can refer to the https://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/80512/active-v-s-passive-ftp-simplified for further details.

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
        ftp.connect(host, port);
        int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftp.disconnect();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not able to connect to the ftp Server ");
        }
        ftp.login(userName, password);
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftp.setBufferSize(100000);
        ftp.setConnectTimeout(1200000);
        ftp.setDataTimeout(1200000);
        ftp.setDefaultTimeout(1200000);
```